# How can I run script files by their shortcuts in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd

Tried naive way with a standard Windows shortcut file and with a cmd.exe, failed like this:

```
D:\...>node tty-checker.js.lnk
D:\...\tty-checker.js.lnk:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { L


SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

Maybe you can suggest a way?

Amazing if there is a general method working not only for .js, but for any other source code file type too.

Comment: Do you need to do this via _.lnk_ files? Couldn't you create a file association between the _.js_ files and the _node_ app?

Comment: Thank you for idea, @CristiFati! I hope that I get you right. I need a more general solution, so it's not only `node` executable that can run .js.lnk files from the console. In other words, I hope to find a way for any executable to run any kind of **.**.lnk files from the console. For example, compiling C program with different falvors of compilators from a **.c.lnk file.